# AWS Apache Issue: setting up the domain and subdomain

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, subdomain

I have already set up a AWS EC2 machine and successfully install the LAMP service. However, I could not use my own domain to visit the website. The only way to visit the website is using its EIP.

The httpd.conf looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName Mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.Mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/subdomain
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, I have modified the A record on go daddy.

the A record looks like this:

```
(They points to the same EIP)
| Host          | Points to | TTL    |
|---------------|-----------|--------|
| @             | the EIP   | 1 Hour |
| www.subdomain | the EIP   | 1 Hour |
```

And Now, I can visit the subdomain.Mydomain.com but can't visit the Mydomain.com.

I was wondering how to fix this?

------------------UPDATES-----------------------

Now I change my httpd.conf to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.Mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, I can visit my website through **www.Mydomain.com**
Since the mydomain.com has been redirected before, so when I visit Mydomain.com (without www), it still being redirected.

How to fix this?